# GridView builder inside a ListView does not lazy load

Tags: android, flutter

As the title says, I need to use a GridView.builder() inside a ListView, and that works fine, but the problem I am facing is that the GridView needs to hold a lot of data, and for some reason, using the GridView inside the ListView does not lazy load only the data that the user can see, but builds the full grid.

I do want to mention that using the Gridview code outside the listview loads the data as expected
Also the listview seems to be working fine, as if the grid is not yet in View, it will only load the grid when needed, but once the grid is triggered, then the full grid is build from 1 go. So it seems my grid view is not lazy loading the data.

Example code:

```
 ListView(
     children: <Widget>[
        buildGridView1(),
        buildGridView2(),
     ],
 )
```

and the method that builds the GridView is something like this:

```
child: ValueListenableBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, List<MyObject>? myList,
        Widget? child) {
     return GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: myList.length,
                  primary: false,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    childAspectRatio: uiConfig.getPosterAspectRatio(2 / 3.5),
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: uiConfig.getPosterSize(),
                    crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final item = myList[index];
                    return CustomWidget(item);
                  },
                );
    },
    valueListenable: xyz,
  )
```

I know a SliverList would have probably been more appropriate, but with SliverList I can't build a sliver to be refreshed automatically as I do here with wrapping the Grid in a ValueListenableBuilder.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this package: https://pub.dev/packages/lazy_load_scrollview

Comment: `SliverList` can be rebuild ("refreshed") like any other widget

Comment: Yes but with my approach, I only rebuild part of the ListView aka only the Grid. since that is the only thing that needs to be refresh. So I know I can refresh the full SliverList, I don't know how to refresh only a particular Sliver

Comment: Do you have the answer? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I do not. Since this post, I have refactored to use the Bloc pattern so the code changed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encounter this issue and resolve it by using Sliver Widget.
I can show a example how it lazy load with the network image.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SliverGridInList(
          myUrlList: List.generate(50, (index) {
            return 'https://picsum.photos/${1080 + index}';
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SliverGridInList extends StatelessWidget {
  const SliverGridInList({
    required this.myUrlList,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> myUrlList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        const SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Text('Title', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
        ),
        SliverGrid.extent(
          childAspectRatio: 1,
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 400,
          crossAxisSpacing: 5,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          children: myUrlList.map((myUrl) {
            return Image.network(myUrl);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]